# How can I use reflection to invoke DomainService.Load method?

Tags: c#, silverlight, reflection, ria

I am trying to build a utility method that will generically load entitycollections using Reflection. The idea is that a programmer using the utility can specify any type of entity and this method will discover the correct EntityQuery and the load the context with what they requested. So, I have collected the Entity type and Where clause from the user, now I am trying to figure out how to invoke the method. Here is what I have:

```
public void Handle(LoadEntityQuery loadQuery, Action<LoadEntityQueryResult> reply)
{
    foreach (var entry in loadQuery.Entities)
    {

        Type entityType = entry.Key;
        Type _contextType = EmployeeJobsContext.Instance.GetType();

        MethodInfo _methodInfo = (from x in _contextType.GetMethods()
                                 where x.ReturnType.BaseType == typeof(EntityQuery)
                                 from y in x.ReturnType.GetGenericArguments()
                                 where y == entityType
                                 select x).FirstOrDefault();
        if (_methodInfo != null)
        {
            var query = _methodInfo.Invoke(EmployeeJobsContext.Instance, null);

           var _loadMethods = from x in _contextType.GetMethods()
                              where x.Name == "Load" &&
                                    x.GetParameters().Length == 3
                              select x;
           MethodInfo _loadMethod = null;

           if (_loadMethods != null)
           {
               foreach (MethodInfo item in _loadMethods)
               {
                   ParameterInfo[] _paramInfo = item.GetParameters();
                   if (_paramInfo[0].ParameterType.BaseType == typeof(EntityQuery) &&
                       _paramInfo[1].ParameterType.IsGenericType &&
                       _paramInfo[1].ParameterType.GetGenericArguments().Length == 1 &&
                       _paramInfo[1].ParameterType.GetGenericArguments()[0].BaseType == typeof(LoadOperation) &&
                       _paramInfo[2].ParameterType == typeof(object))
                   {
                       _loadMethod = item;
                       break;
                   }
               }
           }

           MethodInfo _loadOpMethod = this.GetType().GetMethod("LoadOperationResult");
           Delegate d = Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(LoadOpDel), _loadOpMethod);

           if (_loadMethod != null)
           {
               object [] _params = new object[3];
               _params[0] = query;
               _params[1] = d;
               _params[2] = null;

               _loadMethod = _loadMethod.MakeGenericMethod(entityType);
               _loadMethod.Invoke(_context, _params);
           }
        }           
    }
}

public delegate void LoadOpDel(LoadOperation loadOp);

public void LoadOperationResult (LoadOperation loadOp)
{
    if (loadOp.HasError == true)
    {
        //reply(new LoadEntityQueryResult { Error = loadOp.Error.Message });
        loadOp.MarkErrorAsHandled();
    }
}
```

The foreach loop is iterating a Dictionary>>, where the Key is an Entity type and the value is a Where clause. The first part of code is finding the correct EntityQuery method and invoking it to get the actual query. It then discovers the correct Load overload (I know, likely there is a better way to find the method :) ) This portion of the code works correctly, I am able to discover the correct EntityQuery and the Load method.

For the LoadOperation, I want to use the LoadOperationResult as my delegate method. When I try to run this code however, I receive an exception stating that the delegate type and the method type signatures do not match. I am pretty sure my signature is correct because if I was to call Load directly and pass the function name as the callback normally, this code would execute properly. I am fairly familiar with reflective programming, however throwing Generics and Action callbacks into the mix is a bit above my level at this point. I'm at a loss as to what I am doing wrong, does anyone have any pointers for me? Am I way off? Thanks for your help!!
Jason

Comment: So the exception is thrown at `_loadMethod.Invoke(_context, _params);` or when you are creating the delegate? And I also may be confused about this, but don't you want to create your delegate outside of the loop?

Comment: Sorry, I did not specify whenthis occurs.  I get the exception when I create the delegate.also, I need the delegate to be created in the loop since the load operation is called for every entity in the collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I did not need to use reflection to invoke the Load method (negating the need for the delegate), instead I call Load directly by creating a generic method based on Entity type. Here is what I came up with for anyone interested:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// The Action callback for the LoadEntityQuery handler. This callback is used to respond to the 
    /// LoadEntityQuery when all Load calls are complete. See the Handle method 
    /// </summary>
    private Action<LoadEntityQueryResult> _reply = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Accumulator used to determine when the last entity has been loaded
    /// </summary>
    private int EntityCount { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Collective error container for Errors from the LoadOperation. This is value is returned via
    /// the _reply callback to the calling code.
    /// </summary>
    private List<Exception> Errors = null;

    public void Handle(LoadEntityQuery loadQuery, Action<LoadEntityQueryResult> reply)
    {
        _reply = reply;
        Errors = new List<Exception>();
        EntityCount = loadQuery.Entities.Count();

        MethodInfo _loadOpMethod = this.GetType().GetMethod("Load", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        int _entityCount = loadQuery.Entities.Count();

        foreach (var entry in loadQuery.Entities)
        {
            Type entityType = entry.Key;
            Type _contextType = EmployeeJobsContext.Instance.GetType();

            MethodInfo _methodInfo = (from x in _contextType.GetMethods()
                                      where x.ReturnType.BaseType == typeof(EntityQuery)
                                      from y in x.ReturnType.GetGenericArguments()
                                      where y == entityType
                                      select x).FirstOrDefault();
            if (_methodInfo != null)
            {
                var query = _methodInfo.Invoke(EmployeeJobsContext.Instance, null);
                MethodInfo _typedLoadOpMethod = _loadOpMethod.MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { entityType });

                _typedLoadOpMethod.Invoke(this, new[] { query, entry.Value});
            }
        }
    }

    private void Load<T>(EntityQuery<T> query, Expression<Func<T, bool>> where) where T: Entity
    {
        if (where != null)
            query = query.Where(where);

        EmployeeJobsContext.Instance.Load(query, (loadOp) =>
            {
                EntityCount--;
                if (loadOp.HasError)
                {
                    Errors.Add(loadOp.Error);
                    loadOp.MarkErrorAsHandled();
                }

                if (EntityCount == 0)
                    _reply(new LoadEntityQueryResult { ErrorList = Errors });

            }, null);
    }
```

The handler for the Load operation watches for the last entity to finish loading, then responds to the client that loading is complete (with any errors, should they occur).

Answer (score 0):

Well without knowing anything else about the classes you're using, I can't really test my solution, but when I take the delegate creation out of the for loop I can get it to work. I changed your target method to static:

```
public static void LoadOperationResult(LoadOperation loadOp)
```

and the delegate was created without a problem.

I'm not, let's say, particularly competent in this area, but I think you want to create the delegate once, and simply re-use it when you need it. Why keep creating it over and over?

Comment: Hi Steve, thanks for the input. That is a good point, I do only need to create the delegate once and just reuse it, so where/when did you create it? Did you still associate it with my _params object the same way? THanks!

Comment: @Rockdocta I created it just before the for loop. I didn't actually use it, as I don't have the rest of your project. I ran the code, but never had a non-null _methodInfo variable, so I didn't actually test the delegate. But it was created.

Answer (score 0):

even if `Action<LoadOperation>` and `LoadOpDel` have the same signature you can't implicitly convert between them.  In C# type coercion sometimes makes this appear to not be true but if you are using reflection type coercion obviously isn't going to work its magic.